# Set scroll position on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to set the page scroll on page load. I can set it by div scroll top or just pixel height.

Comment: Using anchors is not an option? If not, set up your code inside the jQuery `.ready()` function and scroll to any position.

Comment: How do you want to set it?

Comment: @feeela anchor is an option, but I be ok with setting it via pixel from top.

Comment: @feeela I have jquery doc ready

Comment: @undefined I don't know how to interact with scroll without `$(window).scroll()` and I don't need the event.

Comment: was this topic really that hard to research? There is even a jQuery method for it  http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop(100);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Use window.load instead because the load of some images might affect your scrolling position

```
$(window).load(function() {
      $(document).scrollTop(100);
});
```